# feel sad or sadness

Tags: word-choice

I see "sad" and "sadness" both can follow the verb feel to express unhappiness.

For example

- Everybody can feel sadness sometimes.
- Everybody can feel sad sometimes.

Is there any difference between the two sentences?

Comment: There's no difference in meaning.

Comment: @Mick , there is a subtle difference. _Sadness_ is a noun telling us _what_ the speaker feels, and _Sad_ is an adverb telling us _how_ she feels. The verb is intransitive in one case, and transitive in the other. Compare _Look at me_ and _You look good._

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is not correct.  "I feel sadness" is not good English.  You can say, "I am filled with sadness," or "I am overcome with sadness," but when you use a sense verb like "feel," what needs to follow is an adjective.

Similarly, we say "I feel tired," not "I feel fatigue."  "I am overcome by fatigue," on the other hand, would be correct because "to overcome" is not a sense verb.

See:
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/sense-verbs/